# Stack canaries can be disabled by compiler?

Tags: security, gcc, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, leakcanary

Who is responsible for inserting the stack canaries in the stack? Is it the OS?
If yes, how can the gcc compiler disable them by using the `-fno-stack-protector` option? Or it is only a flag created using that option and added to the binary to tell the OS to not insert canaries in the stack where the binary is loaded at runtime?

**EDIT: one more question**

Who checks the value of the canaries if they were changed over the execution?
Again if inserted by the compiler, how can be checked by the OS? If inserted by the OS how can it be disabled by the compiler (main question)?

Answer (score 1):

> Who is responsible for inserting the stack canaries in the stack?

The compiler. The code for creating and checking stack canaries is a subset of the code generated by the compiler from the program source code.

For GCC:

> [`-fstack-protector`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)
>
> Emit extra code to check for buffer overflows, such as stack smashing          attacks. This is done by adding a **guard variable** to functions with vulnerable objects. This includes functions that call `alloca`, and functions with buffers larger than 8 bytes. The guards are initialized when a function is entered and then checked when the function exits. If a guard check fails, an error message is printed and the program exits.

The aforementioned "guard variable" is commonly referred to as a [*canary*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/149133/how-big-is-a-canary-word-on-linux-typically):

> The basic idea behind stack protection is to push a "canary" (a randomly chosen integer) on the stack just after the function return pointer has been pushed. The canary value is then checked before the function returns; if it has changed, the program will abort. Generally, stack buffer overflow (aka "stack smashing") attacks will have to change the value of the canary as they write beyond the end of the buffer before they can get to the return pointer. Since the value of the canary is unknown to the attacker, it cannot be replaced by the attack. Thus, the stack protection allows the program to abort when that happens rather than return to wherever the attacker wanted it to go.<sup>[1](https://lwn.net/Articles/584225/)</sup>

Example program:

Source code:

```
int test(int i) {
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    int x;
    int i = 10;
    x = test(i);
    return x;
}
```

Function from binary compiled **without** `-fstack-protector-all`:

```
$ objdump -dj .text test | grep -A7 "<test>:"
00000000004004ed <test>:
  4004ed:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004ee:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f1:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  4004f4:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  4004f7:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004f8:   c3                      retq
```

Function from binary compiled **with** `-fstack-protector-all`:

```
$ objdump -dj .text protected_test | grep -A20 "<test>:"
000000000040055d <test>:
  40055d:   55                      push   %rbp
  40055e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400561:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  400565:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  400568:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax     <- get guard variable value
  40056f:   00 00 
  400571:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)   <- save guard variable on stack
  400575:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400577:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
  40057a:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx   <- move it to register
  40057e:   64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx     <- check it against original
  400585:   00 00 
  400587:   74 05                   je     40058e <test+0x31>
  400589:   e8 b2 fe ff ff          callq  400440 <__stack_chk_fail@plt> 
  40058e:   c9                      leaveq 
  40058f:   c3                      retq
```

---

<sub>[1. "Strong" stack protection for GCC](https://lwn.net/Articles/584225/)</sub>

Comment: Well, thank you for this clarification. I found also that gcc (with stack canaries insertion) modify the function prologue and epilogue who insert and check respectively the canary value, this can be seen from the assembly code in your response. I think also that when the canary is found modified, an exception is raised, catched by the OS which will kill execution process.

Comment: Great explanation. Now if only the compiler behavior was enabled by default.